# Как передавать пользователя через rest django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Есть модель события, которая привязана к пользователю. При создании события через rest задаю все параметры, кроме пользователя, но он ругается, что пользователь - null. При создании через админ панель и сам сайт пользователь берется через request.user, но как сделать это через rest не знаю

models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    """Event which create user"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Пользователь")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name="Название")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Содержание")
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Дата события")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    content = serializers.CharField()
    event_date = serializers.DateTimeField()


    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Event.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.content = validated_data.get(
            'content', instance.content)
        instance.event_date = validated_data.get('event_date',
             instance.event_date)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py(часть сериалайзера):

```
class EventView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        events = Event.objects.all()
        serializer = EventSerializer(events, many=True)
        return Response({"events": serializer.data})

    def post(self, request):
        event = request.data.get('event')
        serializer = EventSerializer(data=event)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            event_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({"success": "Event created successfully"})
```